# rails 3 : How to create a path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I need an explanation about how create new path on rails 3. I want this link for example

```
link_to "eat chocolate", eat_chocolate_user_path(user)
```

be equals to

```
link_to "eat chocolate", :controller => 'user', :action=>'eat_chocolate', :id=> user
```

I read many guides about it, including routing of railsguide. But i still do not know how it exactly work.

Answer (score 10):

add the following line to your routes.rb file.

```
match 'user/eat_chocolate/:id' => 'user#eat_chocolate', :as => :eat_chocolate_user
```

Look up named routes for more info.

Comment: Thank you, i was able to create succesfully routes, but i was unable to give it a name.

Comment: The name of the route is specified with the :as parameter.  So the above should have created eat_chocolate_user_path for you. Is that not working for you?

Answer (score 2):

In some cases it will be better to use `GET`.

Using `match` will accept ALL http verbs `GET` `PUT` `POST` `DELETE` meaning that somebody could potentially mis-use your application.  If all you're doing is showing something in a #show action, you should use this instead

`get 'user/eat_chocolate/:id' => 'user#eat_chocolate', :as => :eat_chocolate_user`